# Using a CSS Selector to select an option in drop down menu using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a CSS selector value as

```
.ng-touched > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(1)
```

I am trying document.querySelectorAll to look for this CSS selector which has a drop down menu and **select the option having the text APPLE**. It is the 2nd option in the drop down menu.
For this I am using this code, but after running the code, the option APPLE is not getting selected

```
document.querySelectorAll(".ng-touched > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(1)")
  .forEach(o => {
     o.value = "APPLE";
  });
```

Please guide me as to where I am going wrong and what necessary changes should I make in the code. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML structure seems wrong to me. An `input` element doesn't contain `options`; `select` elements do. My snippet shows you how you can programmatically assign the value of a `select` dropdown to the 2nd option, APPLE.

It also uses your existing structure (derived from your query), but instead of `input` as the final element, I'm using `select` as, again, an `input` with `options` doesn't make sense semantically. So, my solution may not be answering your question exactly, if my interpretation is wrong. But I hope it can still guide you in the right direction.

```js
const select = document.querySelector(".ng-touched > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > select:nth-child(1)")


// setTimeout used to visualize how GOOGLE changes to APPLE.
setTimeout(() => {

  // You can access the options of the select with .options.
  // Then you can programatically set the selected value by index.
  select.options.selectedIndex = 1
}, 2000)
```

```html
<div class="ng-touched">
  <div style="padding-left: 16px;">

    <div style="padding-left: 16px;">

      <div> </div>
      <div style="padding-left: 16px;">
        <select id="companies">
          <option value="google">GOOGLE</option>
          <option value="apple">APPLE</option>
          <option value="facebook">FACEBOOK</option>
          <option value="amazon">AMAZON</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for guiding, but this code is not helping. Maybe the identifier Iam using is not correct. I found out that the word APPLE in the drop down text is uniquely identified by id="a37d2ef9c498-7" and this identifier code keeps on changing on every page refresh. Only the "-7" is constant  i.ibb.co/m5b4Nr7/identifier.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wrong when you use forEach method. If you want to get value apple you have to use comparison operator like ( '==' ) not assignment operator ( '=' ).

```js
const option = document.querySelectorAll("option");

option.forEach((e) => {
  if (e.value == "apple") {
    console.log(e.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<select>
      <option value="orange">Orange</option>
      <option value="apple">Apple</option>
</select>
```